# re.findall() equivalent to a string.split() loop with inner search

Tags: regex

Is there a regex string `<regex>` such that `re.findall(r'<regex>', doc)` will return the same result as the following code?

```
doc = ' th_is is stuff. and2 3things if y4ou kn-ow ___ whaaaat iii mean)'
new_doc = []
for word in re.split(r'\s+', doc.strip()):
    if not re.search(r'(.)\1{2,}|[_\d\W]+', word):
         new_doc.append(word)
>>> new_doc
['is', 'if']
```

Comment: Please post the actual conditions you desire, and not simply one vague sample output.

Comment: What do you **actually** want from the regex?

Comment: So I've tried to understand it. Do you want a regex that will match the words in the sentence which do not have a repeated letter and do not have a digit, underscore or non-word character?

Comment: I don't get it. Your code works for me. Please post the error/problem you find in your code.

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder, yes the code above works -- I'm asking for a way to do it in one line (w/o a for-loop), perhaps using `re.findall()`.

The conditions desired are as you said "match the words in the sentence which do not have a repeated letter and do not have a digit, underscore or non-word character".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, your current way of getting the matches is the best.

You can't do that without some additional operation, e.g. list comprehension, because `re.findall` with a pattern that contains a capturing group outputs the captured substrings in the resulting list.

Thus, you may either add an outer capturing group and use `re.findall` or use `re.finditer` and get the first group using

```
(?<!\S)(?!\S*(\S)\1{2}|\S*(?!\s)[_\d\W])\S+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dIUYi2/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string must be immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?!\S*(\S)\1{2}|\S*(?!\s)[_\d\W])`  - there cannot be 3 same non-whitespace chars or a char that is a `_`, digit or any non-word char other than whitespace  after any 0+ non-whitespace chars immediately to the right the current location
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

See [the Python demo](http://rextester.com/UZS97185):

```
import re
doc = ' th_is is stuff. and2 3things if y4ou kn-ow ___ whaaaat iii mean)'
new_doc = [x.group(0) for x in re.finditer(r'(?<!\S)(?!\S*(\S)\1{2}|\S*(?!\s)[_\d\W])\S+', doc)]
print(new_doc) # => ['is', 'if']
new_doc2 = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)((?!\S*(\S)\2{2}|\S*(?!\s)[_\d\W])\S+)', doc)
print([x[0] for x in new_doc2]) # => ['is', 'if']
```